# How do I change the Device Name of my Nexus 7 2013 when connecting to a hotspot?

Tags: nexus-7, wifi-hotspot

How do I change the Device Name of my Nexus 7 2013 (not rooted)?

On my Samsung Galaxy S4 hotspot, the Nexus 7 shows up as `android-xxx`, where `xxx` is some random sequence of characters. How do I change the name to something like `geffchang-nexus7`?

Comment: I don't think it is possible to change device name without root. The method mentioned by [RossC](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/40036/rossc) will change the Hotspot name displayed when devices try to connect to Nexus 7.

Answer (score 3):

Unless the OEM has built in the option (Samsung have for example) you cannot change the device name without [root](/questions/tagged/root). The [nexus-7](/questions/tagged/nexus-7) does not have this option.

On the Samsung Galaxy S4 (for example) you can go to *Settings > More > About Device > Device Name* and you can change it directly from there.

For those with root:

```
 su
 getprop net.hostname
 setprop net.hostname <new_hostname>
```

Or simply download a [build.prop editor app from the play store.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.nathan.jf.build.prop.editor&hl=en)  This requires Root also. WARNING: Any changes to this file can stop your device from working or cause unexpected behaviour, do so at **YOUR OWN RISK.**

---

**To change Hotspot name:**

Go to

> Wireless & Networks > Tethering & Portable hotspot.

[image]

Then

> > Tick the box next to Portable Wi-Fi hotspot
> >     Tap Portable Wi-Fihotspot settings and you can edit the Wi-Fi network
> >     name, and choose a password.

[image]

Enter your name there!

Comment: No, I want to change the name of my tablet, not the hotspot name of my tablet. My S4 is the wi-fi hotspot. In the list of connected devices, my Nexus 7 shows up as `android-xxx`. I want the S4 to see this as `geffchang-nexus7`, but NOT through renaming it in S4.

Comment: My apologies, the S4 lets you do this easily... but it seems you cannot on the nexus devices without root. I updated my answer with both options to clarify and how to do it with root. Updated: Can you try settings then on bottom at About Device and change the name there? I don't have my nexus and I'm nearly sure it's specific to the device I do have with me (S4) but it is worth a shot I guess!!

Comment: I've re-updated my answer as far as I know you can't but see if it is in the 'About Device' section. 99% sure you can't but I've expanded the answer for others with this question to include other OEMs, Nexus specific and how to change the Hotspot name also, I've also added the root method of changing it to give all options. Sorry it doesn't seem possible as it stands for you.

Comment: It's not in the `About tablet` section. I might look into rooting it instead.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible without root.

If you are rooted then install a terminal emulator on the tablet. Enter the following:

> su
>
> getprop net.hostname
>
> setprop net.hostname {new_hostname}

The 'getprop' command will return the current hostname, so you can double-check it before setting the new one. Reboot to refresh network assignments.

Taken from [here](http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-4/293909-change-device-name.html) (the method without root didn't show up for me so not including that)

**Or** you could install an app from the [play store](https://play.google.com/store/search?q=Hostname&c=apps) that will allow you to change the host name. I expect they're doing the same thing as the commands above though, as they all require root.